# Symfony - Setting Flash and Checking in TWIG

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to set Flash in my controller, then check in TWIG if a Flash has been set. My problem is that TWIG always reports that my Flash has not been set and I am unsure why.

Controller:

```
$session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Does Not Exist');
```

TWIG:

```
{{ dump( app.session.hasFlash('error') ) }} //outputs false
{{ dump( app.session.getFlashBag().get('error') ) }} //outputs false
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**In Controller**

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('error', 'Does Not Exist');

or 

$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Does Not Exist');
```

**In Twig**

```
{% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('error') %}

    {{ flashMessage }}

{% endfor %}
```

FYI: [Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/controller.html#flash-messages)

Comment: I've tried that, but when I `{{ dump(flashMessage) }}` in TWIG, I don't even see anything appear on the screen.

Comment: The previous guy who worked on the controller created a new session via `$session = new Session();`. Should I be referring to the session via `$session` instead of by `$this->get('session')`?

Comment: Here the latest documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#flash-messages

Comment: Something like this possible? (If user hits F5 then this will be handled in the controller): `if (isset(flashMessage)) { return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:m.html.twig'); } else { //redirect to home page }`

Answer (score 20):

In Controller :

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', "User does not exists.");
```

In View :

```
{% for type, messages in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {% if type == 'error' %}
            {{ message }}
        {% endif %}
        {# Or even with css class rendering:
            <div class="flash-{{type}}">{{message}}</div>
        #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 9):

It is worth noting that in the Symfony 3.3 and up we can use simplified version `app.flashes()`. Example:

```
{% for message in app.flashes('notice') %}
    <div class="flash-notice">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

[Source](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#flash-messages)

Answer (score 5):

Using Symfony 5. If you want to display **all** flashes using bootstrap class naming, simply set the flash type to the bootstrap class name (success/danger/warning... etc)

In the controller set like this:

```
$this->addFlash('success', 'Action completed successfully.');
or...
$this->addFlash('danger', 'An error occurred.');
```

In Twig display once, in a base template for example - like this (notice the simplified app.flashes array var):

```
{% for type, messages in app.flashes %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ type }}">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

it s simplified in symfony 4 (it should works in 3.4 too)

Your controler :

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    // do some sort of processing

    $this->addFlash(
        'notice',
        'Your changes were saved!'
    );
    // $this->addFlash() is equivalent to $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add()

    return $this->redirectToRoute(...);
}
```

Twig :

```
{% for message in app.flashes('notice') %}
    <div class="flash-notice">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I want to wrap ALL messages in a div, but using `{% if app.flashes is not empty %}` clears the messages, and so it is empty in the next `for` loop.  How do I use `peek()` or `peekAll()` like `{% if peekAll() is not empty %}`

Comment: @Chad you can you the following code in your twig if-statement: `app.session.flashbag.peek('notice')|length > 0`

Answer (score 4):

This question is pretty old now but I have not seen this answer yet.

For checking if a flash message with a specific type has been set:

Twig:

```
{% if app.session.flashBag.has('error') %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

The code inside the if statement will be executed, if a message with type "error" has been set. You can use iteration inside, but this is only for checking, if a message exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FlashAlertBundle](https://github.com/rasanga/FlashAlertBundle), it provides a simplified way to handle (add/display) **Symfony flash messages**.

**Available through**
https://github.com/rasanga/FlashAlertBundle
https://packagist.org/packages/ras/flash-alert-bundle

You just need a single line

```
{{ render_flash_alerts() }}
```

to render flash messages